# Connecting to Postgres via python using AAD

Tags: python, postgresql, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory

If I am a member of an AD group that has an AD role defined and connect/select privileges on a Postgres DB, how can I use SQL Alchemy to connect to the DB with my username/pass?

If I just give my username/password, it tells me:

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "<user>"
```

How can I tell it to use AAD for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user ""

I tried to log in to the database with incorrect `DB` admin credentials in `Python`, but I encountered the same result.

[image]

In order to authenticate with `Azure AD` credentials, you need to use an access token.

I have followed this [MS Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication#connect-to-azure-database-for-postgresql-by-using-azure-ad)  & [MS Doc 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/single-server/connect-python) to connect `PostgreSQL` with `Azure AD` authentication.

When connecting, it's best to use the access token as the PostgreSQL user password.

Here is the command to get the access token.

```
az account get-access-token --resource https://ossrdbms-aad.database.windows.net
```

Install the module using the command below before running the `Python` code.

```
  pip install sqlalchemy psycopg2
```

**Python code to connect PostgreSQL**

```py
    import psycopg2
    host = 'sampledatabase.postgres.database.azure.com'
    dbname = 'postgres'
    user = 'user.com'
    password = 'Accesstoken'
    sslmode = 'require'
    conn_string = "host={0} user={1} dbname={2} password={3} sslmode={4}".format(host, user, dbname, password, sslmode)
  conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    print("Connection established")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you! also if you want to do this all in python and remove your cli dependency, you can use the msal library to get the token